# MySQL select date with predefined values if date not exist

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I've got following MySQL query:

```
SELECT Date,
       Fail/(Success + Fail + NA) AS  'Rate'
FROM (
    SELECT CAST( s.date_str AS DATE ) AS  'Date',
           SUM(CASE WHEN k.result = 'SUCCESS' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Success,
           SUM(CASE WHEN k.result = 'FAIL' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Fail,
           SUM(CASE WHEN k.result != 'FAIL' AND k.result != 'SUCCESS' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) NA 
    FROM Session s, KPI k
    WHERE s.id = k.session_id
    GROUP BY Date
)subQuery
```

It shows this result for example:

Date       | Rate
.....................
2015-10-15 | 0.0836
2015-10-16 | 0.0279
2015-10-19 | 0.1569
2015-10-21 | 0.2756

So it shows only result when there's some data..
What I'd like to achieve is when there's no data it shows next date and rate 0.0000 so in that example it'd looks like this:

Date       | Rate
.....................
2015-10-15 | 0.0836
2015-10-16 | 0.0279
2015-10-17 | 0.0000
2015-10-18 | 0.0000
2015-10-19 | 0.1569
2015-10-20 | 0.0000
2015-10-21 | 0.2756

How could I achieve that?

Comment: What is the range of dates you'd like to include in the results? Is it just the dates in between the min and max dates?

Comment: @JRD between current day and last 30 days

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to join to another table that has at least 30 rows to manufacture any dates that do not exist in the data set. Something like:

```
 select * from(
     select curdate() - interval @rn := @rn + 1 day as last_30_date
     from table_with_at_least_30_rows
     join (select @rn := -1) rows limit 30
 ) days
 left join (select curdate() as data_date) d on last_30_date = data_date;
```

Replace `select curdate() as data_date` with your query.