# MySQL select sum with different group by values and empty values

Tags: mysql

let's assume I have several stores which have sometimes different open days (due to  public holiday or something else) and the sales will save in the following table with time stamp:

```
+----------+---------------------+---------------+
| store_id | sales_date          | sales_amount  |
+----------+---------------------+---------------+
|        1 | 2017-11-03 10:32:44 | 100.00        | 
|        1 | 2017-11-03 10:33:49 | 150.00        |
|        1 | 2017-11-04 11:08:24 | 120.00        |
|        1 | 2017-11-05 13:33:57 | 200.00        |
|        2 | 2017-11-03 12:37:34 | 100.00        |
|        2 | 2017-11-05 15:23:49 | 200.00        |
+----------+---------------------+---------------+
```

I would like to display a chart using chart.js.
The first requirement from my client was a filter by an hour.
[Click here for the solution of the first requirement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47097763/mysql-select-sum-with-group-by-and-empty-values)!

But now, he will also be able to filter by date range and also by month.

I have the following SQL:

```
SELECT store_id, DATE(sales_date) as date_hour, sum(sales_amount) as sales_sum 
FROM sales 
GROUP BY store_id, date_hour
```

My **current** result is

```
+----------+-------------+---------------+
| store_id | date_hour   | sales_sum     |
+----------+-------------+---------------+
|        1 | 2017-11-03  | 250.00        | 
|        1 | 2017-11-04  | 120.00        |
|        1 | 2017-11-05  | 200.00        |
|        2 | 2017-11-03  | 100.00        |
|        2 | 2017-11-05  | 200.00        |
+----------+-------------+---------------+
```

My **expected** result is

```
+----------+-------------+---------------+
| store_id | date_hour   | sales_sum     |
+----------+-------------+---------------+
|        1 | 2017-11-03  | 250.00        | 
|        1 | 2017-11-04  | 120.00        |
|        1 | 2017-11-05  | 200.00        |
|        2 | 2017-11-03  | 100.00        |
|        2 | 2017-11-04  |   0.00        |
|        2 | 2017-11-05  | 200.00        |
+----------+-------------+---------------+
```

The range of dates (in this example 3 till 5 of November) varies on filter input.

Is there a chance to do this with MySQL?

Comment: please refer this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33470089/mysql-select-date-with-predefined-values-if-date-not-exist

Comment: manufacturing time periods that don't exist in mysql is a common request with no simple solution.  @AshishVaghasiya is pointing the right direction, if you HAVE to do it in mysql.  The other option is to do it in the downstream code that processes the result set. So if you don't have the option to add a new table to your db, then this will be your best bet.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display (including missing results) in application code